# Diff between Top 1 1 and Select 1 in SQL Select Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a general doubt in sql. What is actually "Top 1 1" will do ?
What is the meaning of the below query ?

```
select top 1 1 from Worker W where not exists (select 1 from Manager M where M.Id = W.Id)
```

what is the diff between select "TOP 1 1" and "SELECT 1" in sql server query ?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`SELECT TOP 1` Means Selecting the very 1st record in the result set

`SELECT 1` Means return 1 as the result set

`SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM [SomeTable] WHERE <SomeCondition>` Means if the condition is true and any rows are returned from the select, only return top `1` row and only return integer `1` for the row (no data just the integer 1 is returned).

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 is selecting very 1st row in the result set of your query and Other 1 will return 1 for any record where there is no corresponding record in the managers table

Comment: So basically it's the old workaround for IIF EXISTS?

Comment: @Creative no not really, it is actually used with exists operator. Cant think of any other use of `SELECT 1 FROM Table`

Answer (score 19):

In the following, the first "1", which is part of the "TOP 1" means to stop after it gets to a single result.  The second "1" is just because the author really does not care what the result is.

```
SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM WORKER
```

is essentially the same as

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM WORKER
```

The only question is whether it would be more efficient in the "EXISTS" part of the query than just

```
SELECT 1 FROM Manager...
```

Answer (score 4):

The request finds if there is at least one worker (top 1) with no manager.
The SELECT 1 clause acts as a "return true".

If there is a manager, the request `select 1 from Manager M where M.Id = W.Id` returns 1. If there is no manager, the request returns NULL.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT TOP 1 1` will select exactly 0 or 1  `1`s.  `SELECT 1` will select `1` exactly N rows, where N is the number of rows that match your criteria.

In your case, it is looking for the **first** (`TOP 1`) worker that does not have a manager.  However, since it's `SELECT TOP 1 1`, all it's doing is looking for the **existence** of a worker that does not have a manager.

Answer (score 1):

its working like true false...
e.g
 select top 1 1 from Items where ItemId=4526000
it will return 1 because  where condition is matching.
if its not matching then , nothing will return.
=>
suppose 
select top 10 1 from Items where ItemId=4526000
it will return 1 for 5 times if ItemId repeated 5 times.