# Pulling first values from xml file in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file that starts with:

```
<SAMPLEPROFILE
    Name="File Name"
    Number="2"
    >
```

I am trying to pull out the Number.

Here is what I am trying:

```
string number = _myXml.GetElementsByTagName("SAMPLEPROFILE").Item(1).Value;
```

When debugging I can see the xml file by hovering over `_myXml`, but I cannot see the number property?

Comment: That's an XML attribute, look in the `Attributes` array

Comment: Add here the detail code which you using to read from XML file.

Comment: You can have a look at [Select XML Nodes by Name C#](http://www.csharp-examples.net/xml-nodes-by-name/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Item` index starts from `0` not `1`, and `Number` is an attribute not the element's value :

```
string number = _myXml.GetElementsByTagName("SAMPLEPROFILE")
                      .Item(0)
                      .Attributes["Number"]
                      .Value;
```

I assumed you're using `XmlDocument` because it has [`GetElementsByTagName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.getelementsbytagname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Simplest Example to read XML and parse as you like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ReadXML("Test.xml");
    }
    private static void ReadXML(string filepath)
    {
        try
        {
            string xmlDatapath = filepath;
            string FirstColumn = "";
            string SecondColumn = "";
            string xmlData = File.ReadAllText(xmlDatapath);
            StringReader stream = new StringReader(xmlData);
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
            DataSet xmlDS = new DataSet();
            xmlDS.ReadXml(reader);
            FirstColumn = xmlDS.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
            SecondColumn = xmlDS.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Here is Test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<SAMPLEPROFILE  
Name="File Name"
Number="2"  
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
string number = _myXml.GetElementsByTagName("SAMPLEPROFILE").Attributes["Number"].Value;
```

Comment: Or use xpath **xmlDoc.selectNodes("//SAMPLEPROFILE/@Number")**.