# NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS and select 1 1?

Tags: sql, sql-server, exists, not-exists

I am very much a beginner and I completely get what `NOT IN` does, but don't really get `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS`.
Even more, I don't understand what this does:

```
SELECT TOP 1 1 
FROM tblSomeTable
```

What does this query actually do?

For reference, I have been working with something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(E_ID)
FROM  tblEmployee e    
INNER JOIN  tblManager m 
      ON e.tbl_ID = m.tbl_ID         
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 
                   FROM tblEmployee e2 
                   WHERE e2.E_ID = e.E_ID 
                       AND isFired = 'N'
                   )
```

I suppose I haven't read/seen a layman's explanation yet that makes sense to me. Even after reading [Diff between Top 1 1 and Select 1 in SQL Select Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359691/diff-between-top-1-1-and-select-1-in-sql-select-query) I still don't get it

Comment: One suggestion, when using `EXISTS` `NOT EXISTS`, it's not necessary to use `SELECT TOP 1` there. A simple `SELECT *` will use the clustered index and fast enough. One more thing, you could also check `EXISTS (SELECT 1/0 FROM A)` and you will see `1/0` is actually not executed. So, using `TOP` in `EXISTS` is really not a necessary.

Comment: @zhongxiao37: I think what you've written there is what this question is actually asking about. Consider converting your explanation into an answer (you might additionally want to expand on the "TOP unnecessary in EXISTS" bit, though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query will get you only top most record (very first record) out of the total rows in result set. So, if your query returns 10 rows .. you will get the first row. Read more about [TOP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)

```
SELECT TOP 1 FROM tblSomeTable
```

In your Second query the part under `()` is a subquery, in your case it's a correlated subquery which will be evaluated once for each row processed by the outer query.

`NOT EXISTS` will actually check for existence of the rows present in subquery

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM tblEmployee e2 WHERE e2.E_ID = e.E_ID AND isFired = 'N'
)
```

Read more about [Correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) as well as  [Subqueries with EXISTS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189259%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The question that I think would actually need answering is whether `EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM MyTable)` is actually necessary.

`Top 1 1` is telling the query to pick the constant "1" for any answer.

The `Top 1` part is telling it to stop as soon as it finds a match and returns "1".

Wouldn't `EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 FROM MyTable)` be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM <table>` will return you the first row with the value as 1 always, which you have defined as constant.

So if you change this to `SELECT TOP 1 2 FROM <table>` it will return the value as 2 always.

Difference between `IN` and `EXISTS` operators in SQL

Please read this:

http://awesomesql.wordpress.com/2009/07/31/difference-between-in-and-exists-operators-in-sql/

Comment: I don't feel the linked resource is very good. It shows how to use it, not what the difference it. It also states that EXISTS performs better, which is not true, that really depends.

Comment: if you have definite set (small set of ) of values then IN clause may have advantage over EXISTS. in all other cases EXISTS it produces better results over IN clause as it has to just evaluate to boolean or  in other words find the occurance  the first occurance