# Query on data ( connected by foreign key )

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to make nice SQL query but need some help on that...

Table A

```
1 "aaa" "STATUS_OK"
2 "bbb" "STATUS_OK"
3 "ccc" "STATUS_OK"
4 "ddd" "STATUS_NOT_OK"
```

Table B

```
1 "Addtional Data1" 1/9/2015 2 (foregin Key = TableA.ID)
2 "Addtional Data2" 2/9/2015 2 (foregin Key = TableA.ID)
3 "Addtional Data3" 3/9/2015 2 (foregin Key = TableA.ID)
4 "Addtional Data4" 4/9/2015 2 (foregin Key = TableA.ID)
```

So Table A's 2 "bbb" entity has 4 additional data in table B

Here I want to extract rows from Table A which

1. Status is `"STATUS_OK"`
2. does not have additional data in last 2 weeks

I thought this about a day. I am familiar with basic SQL syntax but this gives me hard time.

Can any one help me with making this query?

I can fix the problem by adding "update time" in Table A but this solution is not that preferable...

---

If I make this situation in simple SQL,

```
CREATE TABLE table_A(
    ID           int NOT NULL,
    NAME         VARCHAR(20),
    STATUS       VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE table_B(
    ID            int NOT NULL,
    DATA          VARCHAR(20),
    CREATEDATE    DATE,
    A_ID          int,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (A_ID) REFERENCES table_A(ID)
);
```

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved...

Answer (score 0):

One Option is to do this with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT  ID,NAME,[STATUS]
FROM    table_A a
WHERE   a.[STATUS] = 'STATUS_OK'
        AND NOT EXISTS
            (SELECT TOP 1 1
            FROM    table_B b
            WHERE   b.A_ID = a.ID
                    AND DATEDIFF(WEEK,b.CREATEDATE,GETDATE())<=2)
```

EDIT: Here's another Version using `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.NAME, a.[STATUS]
FROM    table_A a
        LEFT JOIN table_B b ON a.ID = b.A_ID 
                                AND DATEDIFF(WEEK,b.CREATEDATE,GETDATE())<=2
WHERE   a.[STATUS] = 'STATUS_OK'
        AND b.A_ID IS NULL
```

EDIT 2: Using a subquery will work too. On small tables there's no differnce in these 3 queries. If you run it against millions of records you have to check which works best for you:

```
SELECT  ID,NAME,[STATUS]
FROM    table_A a
WHERE   a.[STATUS] = 'STATUS_OK'
        AND a.ID NOT IN
            (SELECT b.A_ID
            FROM    table_B b 
            WHERE   DATEDIFF(WEEK,b.CREATEDATE,GETDATE())<=2)
```

Comment: Does TOP in the NOT EXISTS sub-query make any difference? Either rows exists or not.

Comment: If there's a difference it may be small. i just do this `SELECT TOP 1 1` because in bigger queries i see at first sight that this is just checking if anything in this table exsists. And i hate using `*`...maybe kind of personal preference

Comment: these two examples are tested on SQL SERVER, i am not familiar with MySQL but basically it should work here too - i am just not sure if this kind of `DATEDIFF` function is available in MySQL

Comment: @jarlh: has been discussed here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359691/diff-between-top-1-1-and-select-1-in-sql-select-query

Comment: But that's completely different thing, you are doing TOP 1 in a NOT IN sub-query.

Comment: i think this has nothing to do with the question. Just to find an end for this: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlinthewild/2011/04/05/to-top-or-not-to-top-an-exists/   so according to this test there is absolutely NO difference if you are using TOP 1 or not.